# Wordpress search form by category not working?

Tags: wordpress

**Objective**

I am trying to create different search forms for two different landing pages. Thus, users who end up on landing `page A` will only be able to search for products with categories `Man` and `Book`. Users landing on `page B` will only be able to search for products with categories `Beast` and `Funny`.

Here is my example setup in WooCommerce.

[image]

**What I have tried**

Based on this [link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/build-your-own-custom-wordpress-search/), I have tried the following search function for `page A`.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="https://test.com/">

<div>

<label for="s">Search for (Man and Book):</label>

<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />

<input type="hidden" value="1" name="sentence" />

<input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" />

<input type="hidden" value="product_cat" name="man,book" />

<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />

</div>

</form>
```

**Problem**

If I key in `GetAllX` into the search form, I expect to see `GetAllX (Copy 2)` only. Instead, I see `GetAllX (Copy 2)` and `GetAllX`.

Also, when I key in `test`, I expect to see `Test product 2` only. Instead, I see both `Test product 2` and `Test Product`.

**Questions**

1. Why is WordPress behaving like this? Can someone help me out with this, please?
2. If there is an easier way to create search forms for different product categories based on landing pages, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. It was in this line:

```
<input type="hidden" value="product_cat" name="man,book" />
```

It should be instead:

```
<input type="hidden" value="man,book" name="product_cat" />
```

There was a typo in the article I linked to.